# AJAX remove a previously defined jquery and redefine again - Jquery not working on AJAX generated content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

First post, please be gentle..

I am working on a social type page which loads new comments via AJAX prepend.
e.g.

```
<div class 'comment-said'> 
COMMENT HERE
<div class 'likes'>
<a class="react" data-id="<?=$comment->id?>" data-class="Like"><span> 
Like</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

There is a javascript/jQuery function called on page load to activate 'Like' button emoticon functions within the comments.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.react').Reactions({
postUrl: 'addlike.php'
});
</script>
```

top part of the 'react.js' javascript file called by $('.react').Reactions({ :

```
$.fn.Reactions = function(options) {        
var settings = $.extend( {            
postUrl: false, 
defaultText: "Like"                                 
}, options);        
var emo_value;      
var _data_html = '<div style="position:absolute; z-index: 999;" class="_emobar" data-status="hidden"><div class="_emolist">';       
var emojis  = '<img src="emos/Like.png" class="emo" data-emo-value="Like" style="" />';     
emojis = emojis + '<img src="emos/Love.png" class="emo" data-emo-value="Love" style="" />';     
emojis = emojis + '<img src="emos/LOL.png" class="emo" data-emo-value="LOL" style="" />';   

_data_html = _data_html + emojis;       
_data_html = _data_html + '<br clear="all" /></div></div>';     

$(_data_html).appendTo($('body'));
```

However, as new comments are dynamically added, the originally declared **'$('.react').Reactions({'**  function does not work.

As a workaround, I have got it to repeat the **"$('.react').Reactions({"** function call on each new comment added.  This works, but it's compound adding with each new comment, as the **Reactions** code is appending to **$(body)**

So on AJAX generated comments, each time the AJAX adds a new comment I'm ending up with multiple '_emolist' divs

```
<div class 'comment-said'> 
COMMENT HERE
<div class 'likes'>
   <a class="react" data-id="<?=$comment->id?>" data-class="Like"><span> Like</span>

<div class="_emolist" style="width: 250px;"><img src="emojis/Like.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="Like" style=""><img src="emojis/Love.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="Love" style=""><img src="emojis/LOL.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="LOL" style=""><br clear="all"></div>
<div class="_emolist" style="width: 250px;"><img src="emojis/Like.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="Like" style=""><img src="emojis/Love.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="Love" style=""><img src="emojis/LOL.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="LOL" style=""><br clear="all"></div>
<div class="_emolist" style="width: 250px;"><img src="emojis/Like.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="Like" style=""><img src="emojis/Love.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="Love" style=""><img src="emojis/LOL.svg" class="emoji" data-emoji-value="LOL" style=""><br clear="all"></div>

</a>
</div>
</div>
```

SO..

Is there a way to unset the **'$('.react').Reactions({'** call and then declare it again with each new item?

I've searched Google and this site, and can't find anything that works in this case

TIA, Mike

Answer (score 0):

You do have to re-initialize the plugin after loading new content.  But you *don't* have to re-initialize it for *every* matching element on the page.  Restrict the matched set to only the newly loaded content.

You're not showing the AJAX code which loads the new content, but *presumably* when you do that you have some way to identify the specific container into which you are loading that content, or the specific element you're loading.  (If not, you will need to do that.)

Let's say for the sake of argument that, upon loading the new content, you have a reference to an element via jQuery which uniquely identifies just the new content.  For example:

```
let newDiv = $('.comment-said').last();
```

You can use that in your selector to initialize the plugin:

```
$('.react', newDiv).Reactions({
    postUrl: 'addlike.php'
});
```

This would match only the ".react" elements within that `newDiv` element.  You may not even need a separate variable, you could more specifically select directly:

```
$('.comment-said').last().find('.react').Reactions({
    postUrl: 'addlike.php'
});
```

Or any variety of ways in jQuery to target specifically the element(s) you want to target.  Ultimately, all you need to do when re-initializing the plugin is more specifically identify the element(s) you want to initialize, rather than all ".react" elments on the entire page.

Comment: I tried those and the jQuery is loading,  but I'm still getting the multiples - I'm sure because of the   appendTo($'body')  in the react.js.
I think I need to pass a second setting, and get it to appendTo that.